# React.js modify child element on parent click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a following react component:

```js
<li key={contact.id} class="option contact-item">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <a><span>{contact.name.slice(0, 1)}</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <div class="label">
            <div class="name">{contact.name}</div>
            <div class="status">{contact.status}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="select-container">
            <div class="select">
                <i class="icon-check"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

I need to toggle the color of `<i class="icon-check"></i>` when clicking the whole `<li>`

How can I do that?

Comment: Put a relevant code .. complete all component with `render` function .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, in react, you don't use `class`, you use `className`.

See this for full code: https://codepen.io/pen?editors=0010

Using state, you can change styles/classes/etc

```
  _handleClick(key) {
    let clicked = this.state.myList.filter(f => f.id === key)[0];
    this.setState({ clicked: clicked });
  }

  _changeColor(key) {
    if (this.state.clicked.id === key) {
      return 'icon-checked';
    }
    else 
      return 'icon-check';
  }

  _renderList() {
    return this.state.myList.map(contact => (
      <li key={contact.id} 
        onClick={() => this._handleClick(contact.id)}
        className="option contact-item">
        <i className={this._changeColor(contact.id)}></i>
        {contact.name}
      </li>
    ));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <ul>
          {this._renderList()}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I use transform-class-properties webpack plugin, so I can use `class`.

Comment: The problem of this approach is that number of `<li>`s is dynamic, how to handle state for every item individually?

Comment: Ahh right. You didn't mention the list stuff in your question. Updated the codepen link

Answer (score 1):

You can set "changeColor" state on `<li>` click and your `<i>` can handle this state. If you change component state React will rerender your component.

```
<li onClick={this.changeColor()} key={contact.id} className="option contact-item">
<div className="thumbnail">
    <a><span>{contact.name.slice(0, 1)}</span></a>
</div>
<div className="text">
    <div className="label">
        <div className="name">{contact.name}</div>
        <div className="status">{contact.status}</div>
    </div>
    <div className="select-container">
        <div className="select">
            <i className="icon-check" style={if (this.state.colorChanged) {color: 'red'}}></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
changeColor() {
   this.setState({colorChanged: true});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a simple example for you, it works with a sinle list item Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/thj597ns/1/) out.

If you have a list of items, you need to add a one more component for `List` itself with `onToggleListItem` method, which will handle the state change. The state of all list items should be store there. In `ListItem` component you call the `onToggleListItem` method with a contact `id` so you can identify which list item was changed.

```
handleButtonClick() {
    this.props.onToggleListItem(this.props.contact.id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of a state and change the state on click of `li`

```js
var Hello = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      colorClass: ''
    }
  },
  toggleClass() {
    if(this.state.colorClass == '') {
      this.setState({colorClass: 'someColor'});
    } else {
       this.setState({colorClass: ''});
    }
  },
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <li onClick={this.toggleClass}>
          Some text
          <i className={"icon-check " + this.state.colorClass}>value</i>
        </li>  
      </div>
    );
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
.someColor {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: How to use state properly if number of list numbers is dynamic and they all need individual control?

Comment: @fivepointseven you create an array  corresponding to each li and then change the corresponding state when an individual li is clicked.